# Trying to effect parent element by hovering child element

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, css-animations, css-animation-direction

CSS

```
.tilt-box{
    
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;  
    display: flex;        
    flex-direction: column;
    perspective: 500px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateX(-0deg) rotateY(0deg);  
}
.over:nth-child(4){left:66%;top:0;border: 2px solid red;}
.over:nth-child(4):hover ~ .tilt-box  {
    
    transform:translateZ(50px) rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(20deg);  
    transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

HTML

```
<a className='card-continer' href={props.link}>          
      <div className='tilt-box'> 
          <div className='bar' />
          <div className='card-title'>{props.name}</div>
          <div className='bar-2' />
          <div className='over'/>
          <div className='over'/>
          <div className='over'/>
          <div className='over'/>
          <div className='over'/>
          <div className='over'/>
         
        </div>
     
    </a>
```

I am tying to effect the parent element (tilt box) by hovering on the child element (over). but it doesn't seem to work. what the issue here?